# Почему console.log(obj.s) выводит в консоль undefined?

Tags: javascript

Есть такой кусочек кода.

```
var obj = {
    a: 1
};

console.log(obj.s)
```

Как я понимаю, я создал один объект. Под него зарезервировался кусочек памяти, в который поместили поле `a` со значением равным 1. Т.е. больше в этом кусочке памяти ничего нет. Соответственно, при `console.log(obj.s)` я ожидал увидеть в консоли ReferenceError. Однако при обращении к несуществующему полю выводит undefined, как будто поле `s` у объекта есть, но ему не присвоено значени.
Что я упустил в своих рассуждениях?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы инициализировали объект `obj` с параметрами `{a: 1}`. Получается что объект `obj` существует, и вы можете из любой точки кода, после его объявляения создать\удалить\изменить любое любое его свойство(которое разрешено менять). К примеру:

```
var obj = {
    a: 1
};

obj.hello = 'Hello!';

console.log(obj);  // Выведет: {a: 1, hello: 'Hello!'}
```

В вашем случае вы выводите `console.log(obj.s)`, когда `s` вы еще не определили, что и означает `undefined`.

Comment: Можно назвать эту операцию "Magic access".

Comment: Я правильно понял, что при создании объекта выделяется нефиксированый кусок памяти?

Comment: Да, на это он и динамический.